# Why do i get message no such file or directory when i am trying to set my environments on hydro?

Tags: ros, source, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to set the environment setup after installing the ROS full package using terminal. I get the following message:
kadir@kadir:~$ echo "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
kadir@kadir:~$ source ~/.bashrc
bash: /opt/ros/cturtle/setup.bash: No such file or directory

what am i doing wrong?

P.S beginner

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155286/why-do-i-get-message-no-such-file-or-directory-when-i-am-trying-to-set-my-environments-on-hydro?/) by [Abdul](https://answers.ros.org/users/14906/abdul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is still an old entry to `/opt/ros/cturtle/setup.bash` in your `~/.bashrc`. Just remove that line.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul](https://answers.ros.org/users/14906/abdul/) on 2014-04-20**:
must i remove the whole file or just the line in my setup.bash file? and if line which line?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-20**:
No, just the line that contains cturtle.